# MongoDB expireAt doesn't fire immediately

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I set a document to expire at exactly **2022-09-10T01:42:00.000+00:00**

But the document doesn't get deleted immediately, several seconds passed by before it eventually gets deleted.

Is there a way to make expireAt fire immediately the time is reached? It shouldn't wait for an extra second at all?

This is the structure of my schema

```
const EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        expireAt: { type: Date, expires: 0 }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

EventSchema.index({ "expireAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 })
```

My use case is mongoose.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [MongoDB TTL index feature](https://%20https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/) will remove the document some time after it has expired.

> The TTL index does not guarantee that expired data will be deleted
> immediately upon expiration. There may be a delay between the time
> that a document expires and the time that MongoDB removes the document
> from the database.
>
> The background task that removes expired documents runs every 60
> seconds. As a result, documents may remain in a collection during the
> period between the expiration of the document and the running of the
> background task. MongoDB starts deleting documents 0 to 60 seconds
> after the index completes.
>
> Because the duration of the removal operation depends on the workload
> of your  mongod  instance, expired data may exist for some time beyond
> the 60 second period between runs of the background task.

Similar expire functionality could be implemented in your application if more accurate timing is required.

Comment: I see. That explanation makes alot of sense